# meaning of "r" value when calculating mean +/- SD

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, mean, standard-deviation

What is the meaning of "r" in cases such as the one in page 7 of this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6104194/pdf/fninf-12-00051.pdf

And how should we calculate[image] it?

Answer (score 1):

In this paper, $r$ refers to the [Spearman rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient), although more generally, $r$ can refer to any kind of correlation.

In the beginning of the methods section, they explain this as follows:

> To quantify the prediction performance, we calculated the Spearman rank correlation between true and predicted labels using test data.

In particular, the section you circled appears to be referring the the results shown in figure **2B**, where the $y$-axis shows the rank correlation $r$.

In other words, they say that especially for smaller sample sizes, SOLR outperforms the other methods, because the Spearman rank correlation between the actual outcome and that predicted by the model is higher for SOLR.